# Trouble converting recursive case to Haskell

Tags: python, dictionary, haskell

I have the following python code:

```py
def win(start, adjList):
  if len(adjList[start]) == 0: return True

  else:

    for vertex in adjList[startingPoint]:

      adjListCopy = copy.deepcopy(adjList)
      adjListCopy[start].remove(vertex)

      if (win(vertex, adjListCopy)): return False

  return True
```

Here `adjList` is a dictionary, like `{0: [1,2], 2: [3], 3: []}` and start is a index to look at, in this case assume start is `0`. Then it will return if we can win if we start at `0`.

In haskell I will represent the dictionary as a `Map`

Here is my code so far:

```hs
win adjList start =
    if (adjListAtstarting) == Just [] || (adjListAtstarting) == Nothing
        then True
    else
        False
        -- loop through each item in the map, and recurse

    where adjListAtstarting = Map.lookup start adjList
```

I need help with the recursive case in haskell. I know that I can perform the `adjListCopy[start].remove(vertex)` using the `Map.adjustWithKey` function. The main reason I have trouble is because of the `for` loop.

Comment: What is `startingPoint`? If this is just a typo of `start` then your python is overly complicated because you don't need the `if` condition because you `return True` if you drop out of the `for` loop and an empty adjacency list would immediately drop out.

Comment: Sorry it should just be start, okay yes I can do that, but still the recursive case stands

Comment: Do not delete your question when you get your answer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```hs
import qualified Data.Map as Map

win adjList start = not $ any f adjListAtstarting
    where adjListAtstarting = Map.findWithDefault [] start adjList
          f vertex = win (Map.adjust (filter (vertex /=)) start adjList) vertex
```

Since you want to handle `Just []` and `Nothing` the same anyway, I used `findWithDefault` instead of `lookup` so you don't have to deal with the `Maybe` at all. As AChampion pointed out, you don't need the `if` test, as the right thing automatically happens if the list is empty.

`not $ any f adjListAtstarting` calls function `f` on each of the elements of `adjListAtstarting`, and returns `True` if all of the calls to `f` returned `False`, but returns `False` if any of the calls to `f` returned `True`. This matches your Python for loop, which immediately returns `False` if the inner test is ever `True`, and returns `True` if the loop exits because the inner test was always false.

`filter (vertex /=)` takes a list, and returns a list with all of the elements except for `vertex`. (Note: You used `remove` in Python, which only removes the first occurrence of the element from the list. This will remove all of the matching elements from the list. If lists will never contain two of the same element, then this is fine. If they do, then you'll need to use [the `delete` function (imported from `Data.List`)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:delete) instead.)

`Map.adjust (filter (vertex /=)) start adjList` calls `filter (vertex /=)` on the `start` element of `adjList`, and returns a map where the result of that call is the replacement for the `start` element in the input, and all other elements are the same. (You only need `adjust` and not `adjustWithKey`, since the change you're making to the value doesn't depend on the key.)

Comment: Thanks for this! I like the `filter` command. I was going to manually delete the item from the list but it seems like filter does the job! Actually a question, you say I only need `adjust`. But in the python code, the adjust that I make does depend on the key, its `adjListCopy[start].remove(vertex)`, where `start` is the key. Is this not dependent?

Comment: @KSplitX You're only using the key to choose which value to adjust, and passing `start` as a parameter to `adjust` already takes care of that. You only need `adjustWithKey` if the new value depends on the key, rather than just depending on the old value. `filter (vertex /=)` does its job with just the old value.

Comment: Hmm one more question actually, the `any` command takes a function and a list, and return True if at least one matches. In our case, we are never returning True or False anywhere, so where does it get its input from? In python it is clear where the True and False comes from, but not in haskell?

Comment: @KSplitX It comes from `any`. When you call `any` on an empty list, it ignores the function you pass it and just returns `False`. Since each level of recursion applies a `not`, the final `True` or `False` depends on whether there were an odd or even number of levels of recursion down to this base case.

Comment: Where would I add a true or false in the haskell code for clarity purposes?

Comment: @KSplitX If you really want those constants in the code, you could replace `not $ any f adjListAtstarting` with `if any f adjListAtstarting then False else True`, but that's widely considered to make the code *less* clear.